# How can I make sure that the error i created is only given when letters are typed but not deciamls?

Tags: python

```
if CF == '2':
    #taking temperature in fahrenheit
    while True:
        try:
            fahrenheit = input("Enter temperature degree in fahrenheit:")
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Please use numbers")
            continue
        if fahrenheit.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            print("Error: Please use numbers")
            continue
    fahrenheit = float(fahrenheit)

    #Coversion formula
    conv_for = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9

    #calculation for celsius
    celsius = conv_for
    print("%02f degrees in fahrenheit is equal to %02f degrees in celsius" %(fahrenheit,celsius))
    if "%02f degrees in fahrenheit is equal to %02f degrees in celsius" %(fahrenheit,celsius) ==\
    "%02f degrees in fahrenheit is equal to %02f degrees in celsius" %(fahrenheit,celsius):
        input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

When I run the script it gives me the error when I type letters, as expected, but when I type any number with a decimal point it also gives me the error. How can I fix this? Thank you. **The error is meant to be there for letters but just not for any numbers**

Answer (score 2):

`isdigit()` returns True only if all digits are numbers, thus a floating point number string will return False.

You can simply move `fahrenheit = float(fahrenheit)` inside the try-except and remove the else and it will work

Answer (score 0):

isdigit() returns True only if all digits are numbers, thus a floating point number string will return False.

so you can use this also:

```
  if (isinstance(fahrenheit, int)) or (isinstance(fahrenheit, float)):
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I am knda new to all this, so what does that line of code do?

Comment: check if given value is integer  or float

Comment: isinstance returns if the object is an instance of the given class or a subclass of it. Since fahrenheit is the returned value from input it will always be of type str and thus your if condition will always evaluate to False

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the 
`if fahrenheit.isdigit():`
 with
`if fahrenheit.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():`

This should do the job with minimal change in your code.

Comment: It would break if an ip adress is given e.g. "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Yeah, there you go.